# Add to Cart Button Not Working - Magento

Tags: magento, prototypejs, cart

I'm having an issue with the Add to Cart Button on my website. The error I am receiving is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
```

The link to the preview of this site is:

http://southeastsupfix.safetechhosting.co.uk/index.php/cp5000-429.html

Here is the full list of errors that I get:

[image: Errors]

I am sensing a possible JQuery conflict but I can't quite see where.

In terms of the inclusion of files, I had added these in the `head.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JQ/prototype.js"></script>
```

I have also tried the latest version of JQuery but I get the same issues.

If anyone has experienced this before I'd be great if I could get some information.

Comment: Do you have noconflict?

Comment: That's something I didn't mention, sorry. I have tried $ = JQuery.noConflict();, JQuery.noConflict(); and JQuery.noConflict(true);. In all of my custom work where I have used JQuery. No luck though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $ in your jquery code with 'jQuery' like $('body') to jQuery('body')